# z3: Is it possible to adjust the branching heuristics in Z3?

Tags: logic, constraints, z3, smt, z3py

This is a follow-up question of [What is the importance of the order of the assertions in Z3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346226/what-is-the-importance-of-the-order-of-the-assertions-in-z3)

Given that Z3 uses DPLL algorithms. Suppose I have some knowledge about which variables are more critical. Is it possible that I make Z3 solver to branch on these variables first when evaluating my logic problem so as to boost the performance or efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but there is no convenient interface for it at the moment. You'd have to hack the source code a bit, but if you really know that you have to branch on particular variables first it may be worth the effort.