# Have Z3 prioritize certain Boolean variables when branching/searching for a model

Tags: z3, smt, sat

I have a large SAT/SMT formula ranging over two (disjoint) sets of variables:

1. a relatively small set `X` of Boolean variables (< 1000) and
2. a much larger set `Y` of Boolean (and perhaps Integer/Real) variables.

My formula is such that the values of the variables from `X` determine the values of the variables from `Y` completely. Consequently, it would be great if Z3 prioritized the variables from `X` when searching for a model (in fact, it would be even better if Z3 did not branch on any of the variables from the set `Y`).

Is there a way to provide this information to Z3?

Comment: I know for sure that [MathSAT](http://mathsat.fbk.eu/index.html) has a function called `msat_add_preferred_for_branching` in its API which can be used for exactly this situation. I couldn't find its z3 equivalent by navigating the github repository, though.. so I am also interested in the answer to this question. It looks like [something similar has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885295/z3-is-it-possible-to-adjust-the-branching-heuristics-in-z3) in the past, but perhaps something has changed.

Comment: I recommend filing an issue at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues to ask if an API might be available. (Note that this will definitely not be via the smtlib interface, but using the programmatic API somehow.)