# z3py: why does the check time vary so much after renaming the variable?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I observed that the check time of my logical formulas written in z3py changed a lot (from ~60s to ~30s, about 50%) after I removed "-" in the names of the variables that I defined.

E.g.,

```
vec = IntVector('vec-1',10)
```

to

```
vec = IntVector('vec1',10)
```

Is this something expected? If so, why?

Comment: Probably, one of those forms has a name collision. In that case Z3 references the same constant twice instead of throwing an error. So you are solving a different formula.

Comment: Huh, this is interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Probably, one of those forms has a name collision. In that case Z3 references the same constant twice instead of throwing an error. So you are solving a different formula.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Could you please provide an example (SMTLib or Z3Py) that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I can try to synthesize one.

Comment: I think this ticket explained the reason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619592/z3-timing-variation/15627388#15627388

Comment: @Zhongjun'Mark'Jin Nice! Thank you